# matmul function for vector with tensor multiplication in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensor, vector-multiplication

In general when we multiply a vector `v` of dimension `1*n` with a tensor `T` of dimension `m*n*k`, we expect to get a matrix/tensor of dimension `m*k`/`m*1*k`. This means that our tensor has `m` slices of matrices with dimension `n*k`, and `v` is multiplied to each matrix and the resulting vectors are stacked together. In order to do this multiplication in `tensorflow`, I came up with the following formulation. I am just wondering if there is any built-in function that does this standard multiplication straightforward?

```
T = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((m,n,k)), name="tensor") 
v = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((1,n)), name="vector")  
c = tf.stack([v,v]) # m times, here set m=2
output = tf.matmul(c,T)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with:

```
tf.reduce_sum(tf.expand_dims(v,2)*T,1)
```

Code:

```
m, n, k = 2, 3, 4
T = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((m,n,k)), name="tensor") 
v = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((1,n)), name="vector")  


c = tf.stack([v,v]) # m times, here set m=2    
out1 = tf.matmul(c,T) 

out2 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.expand_dims(v,2)*T,1)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  n_out1 = sess.run(out1) 
  n_out2 = sess.run(out2)
  #both n_out1 and n_out2 matches
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a better way, but it sounds like you could use `tf.map_fn` like this:

```
 output = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.matmul(v, x), T)
```