# N-D tensor matrix multiplication with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, matrix-multiplication, tensor

Consider I have a set of vectors `A` and I want to multiply each vector in `A` with a tensor `T` to finally have a tensor `y` in which each slice matrix is the result of the multiplication of vector `v` in `A` with `T`:

If `X` consists of only one vector, then the following code works (thanks to the answer in [matmul function for vector with tensor multiplication in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50300972/matmul-function-for-vector-with-tensor-multiplication-in-tensorflow)):

```
tf.reduce_sum(tf.expand_dims(v,2)*T,1)
```

But if `X` consists of several vectors, how would be the code for multiplication?

For example, I have the following values for `A` (with `2` vectors) and `T`:

```
A = tf.constant([1,2,3,4], shape=[2,2], dtype=tf.float32) #v1 =[1,2], v2=[3,4]
T = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], shape=[2,2,2], dtype=tf.float32)
```

I want to get the following output by multiplying `A` to `T`:

```
[[[ 7. 10.]
  [19. 22.]]

 [[15. 22.]
  [43. 50.]]]
```

An application to this question, is the batch gradient descent in linear regression  `y = AX +b`, in which I have a set of vectors but instead of training a weight matrix `X`, I want to train a tensor `T`, so the output `y` would be a tensor in which each matrix in the tensor is the output of the multiplication of input vector with `T`.

Note that, In general when we multiply a vector `v` of dimension `1*n` with a tensor `T` of dimension `m*n*k`, we expect to get a matrix/tensor of dimension `m*k/m*1*k`. This means that our tensor has `m` slices of matrices with dimension `n*k`, and `v` is multiplied by each matrix and the resulting vectors are stacked together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`tf.tensordot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensordot):

```
tf.tensordot(A, T, axes=[-1, -2])
```

Or,

```
tf.squeeze(tf.tensordot(A[:, None], T, axes=[2, 1]))
```

`eval`'ing this gives

```
array([[[ 7., 10.],
        [19., 22.]],

       [[15., 22.],
        [43., 50.]]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, such a simple solution. I could not fit the right axis in ``tf.tensordot``